# Optimizing Google Maps performance for Mobile?

Tags: android, mobile, maps

I'm currently developing a mobile application using html5 + phonegap, and everything is working well.. The only issue I'm having is that scrolling through a google map on a phonegap made native app it's sluggish and slow, zooming on the map is quite slow as well. Is there any way to increase map rendering speed / tile loading?

Any help in speeding up map loading is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm doing the exact same thing! Haven't found a way to actually speed up the map (I'm assuming if it's running as fast as google's mobile web version then it's as fast as it can go). Accidentally made it a lot slower once though by adding event listeners for swipe events, so make sure you don't do that..